Jenkins connect to the remote Docker Engine, build image failed
My problem is very similar to the situation here(DOCKER_HOST environment variable on windows), but a bit more complex.
I am learning CI/CD and my environment consists of Docker 1.47.0 on Windows 11 with WSL2 as the Docker engine, and a Spring Boot application using Maven 3.9.8 as the dependency manager. I am also using the fabric8io Docker Maven Plugin(https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin).
In my lesson, I need to create a Jenkins pipeline task that first retrieves my project from Git, then builds it. Since I am using the Docker plugin, I can also create a Docker image. Finally, I want to run the image in a container using a .sh script.
Btw both the Git service and Jenkins are running on my local Docker service.

I have enabled "Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS" in Docker Desktop setting and set the  value in pom.xml to "tcp://localhost:2375". 

I can successfully build my project and create a Docker image in my local environment.

However, when I try to run the task in Jenkins, specifically when building the Docker image, I encounter the following error: 
I have tried many different values for 'dockerHost' label, but all failed.
if set to host.docker.internal:2375

if dont set

if set to http://127.0.0.1:2375

...
My question is: If I am using WSL2 to run Docker containers (with Git and Jenkins services in my case), how can I enable Jenkins to connect to the Docker service and build images successfully?
In my lesson, they are using virtualBox to create a Linux environment and run Docker on that, which is different from my env.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.  Are you actually developing your own code, or trying to set up a CI environment?  (Another site like [devops.se] might be more appropriate for the latter.)  The "expose daemon without TLS" Docker Desktop option is a major security exposure, and you should almost never turn it on; I'd expect the Jenkins Docker integration should be able to use the normal Docker socket path.

Thank you for reminding me, I have tried @Iterokun's solution - mount 'docker.sock' file -  Now I can connect to my docker service from jenkins container without enable 'Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS'.

It's a pretty standard setup for someone on Windows to run Jenkins locally. You are missing two pieces:

Run your jenkins container as root. Obviously you are not going to do that with your actual production setup, or even with any sandbox, but user permissions can be figured out later once your networking understanding is solid
Mount your docker socket inside the jenkins container with --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock. Now jenkins should be able to connect to it using standard unix socket notation unix:///var/run/docker.sock


Docker Desktop
uses WSL 2 as the default backend
and there's also Jenkins for Windows. The network connectivity merely depends where you might install Jenkins. Even in a virtual network, it will be able to connect when it's on the same host or in the same network segment.
Comparing these should explain the concrete differences:

Virtalbox Chapter 6. Virtual Networking

Docker Container networks


Running docker info should show the hostname & port to connect to.
On Linux this might be the docker daemon socket /var/run/docker.sock.
Maybe try to connect with the protocol? Alike: http://host.docker.internal:2375.
On the first screenshot, there is no port :2375 mapped -> EXPOSE 2375.
Depending if the host is Windows or Linux, it's either:

tcp://0.0.0.0:2375
unix:///var/run/docker.sock

See Enable TCP port 2375 for external connection to Docker.

Thanks for comments. I think the main reason for the error is I did not mount docker.sock inside jenkins container to my docker service's docker.sock inside WSL2. With add --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock when build jenkins container, I can connect to docker service from jenkins container now if I set dockerHost to unix:///var/run/docker.sock in pom.xml. And dont have to enable Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS in docker setting.
